# What does "ship" mean in football (soccer)?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does "ship" mean in football (soccer) context?

55 min: Leicester **ship** possession on the edge of their own box, Evans struggling to reach the ball. They’re fortunate that Mane dawdles with space ahead of him on the left, and that Thiago subsequently miscontrols.

Comment: In play-by-play you should keep in mind the possibility that the speaker has said something incorrect. They have to spend an hour (or more) spilling out words, trying to stay "exciting", while also watching the action. It's not rare that they say stuff that is just strange. Not saying that is necessarily the case here. Would need to listen in context. But learning from pay-by-play has this challenge.

Answer (score 1):

The verb to ship has many senses and the relevant one here is to send away. You ship goods to your relatives in a distant country. It is being used here figuratively to mean that they gave up possession to the other side.